# group chat messages according to the users username

Tags: mysql, database

I m creating a chat system for my website but i m  stuck in a lil bit problem i want to group the messages on other users username to which the current user has talked to lets say i have 4 users and three conversations. in conversation 1 user1(john) talked to user2(smith) and in conversation2 user2(smith) talked to user3(michael) and in conversation3 user1(john) talked to user3(michael) so when user1 logedin to his account in his inbox there will be displayed two conversations with username smith and other with username michael and so on ..
here are my tables ..

1.**Users:**

- id
- username
- password

2.**conversations:**

- conversation_id
- from_user
- to_user

3.**messages:**

- message_id
- conversation_id
- user_id
- message_text
- message_date
- seen

it has to be like facebook messanger... anykind of help will be appreciated thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search that way

```
SELECT conversation_id, from_user AS userid FROM conversations WHERE to_user   = 'the_loggued_user'
UNION
SELECT conversation_id, to_user   AS userid FROM conversations WHERE from_user = 'the_loggued_user'
```

Joining user table :

```
SELECT C.conversation_id, C.userid, U.username
FROM(
    SELECT conversation_id, from_user AS userid FROM conversations WHERE to_user   = 'the_loggued_user'
    UNION
    SELECT conversation_id, to_user   AS userid FROM conversations WHERE from_user = 'the_loggued_user'
    ) C
INNER JOIN Users U ON U.id=C.userid
```

Comment: thank you sir it is doing the trick but the userid which is returned after executing this query then how would it be used for retriving the username from the users table

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know if this is your stuck position but I'm gonna try to help.

First of all, you need when someone send a message you need to check in **Conversation** table if there is already a conversation if not you'll create a one but you need to add a new column which stores the date of the last message sent or received and name it **Last_Message** and when someone sent a message you update the date and time in that column then you'll insert the message sent by the user to **Messages** table.

Now, when user open his inbox you need just a query to select the conversation that matches his username in **from_user** or **to_user** columns sorted by the date and time stored in the column **Last_Message**.

Comment: yes sir i can understand your first logic about creating conversations if not exist but how would i group the conversation of current user to which users he has been talked to by displaying that users usernames and when clicked on it the whole chat history between these two users appears but the problem is grouping the current user conversations with other users on their usernames

Comment: You'll group the conversations by selecting all the conversations which their "from_user" or "to_user" columns matches the logged in user username and then show them in the inbox, to show the usernames of them you'll need to check if the matching process that we did was with the "from_user" column then you would show the "to_user" column and vice versa.
Then when logged in user click on one of the conversations you'll open the chat page and select all messages from "Messages" table which matches the two users and sort them by the time sent.